# QTreeWidgetItem does not get Checked

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I am trying to Check Tree items from a function after the Tree is initialized. Check marks never appear. I'm not sure if I need to 'refresh' the Tree or that I am not interacting with the right object.

I've read about this widget a lot and I see the same question more or less on several websites but the answers are 8+ years old, two pages of code or I just don't understand them.

What am I doing wrong here? Why are there no check marks showing up in the tree when I call checkActiveTreeItems()?

After a REST call, I want to update the checked items in the tree. This seems to be ok but the items never get checked.

```
def checkActiveTreeItems(self):
    for label in self.transactie['transactie']['labels']:
        test = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([label])
        test.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

This is the function that creates the tree, I do not call it again after setting the QTreeWidgetItem to Checked in the function above.

```
def initTree(self):
    print("initTree")
    self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.gridLayoutWidget)

   self.treeWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)
    self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")

    inkomstenstructuur = requests.get(url="http://localhost:32769/_db/piekenpijp/incoming/inkomstenstructuur")
    iscontent = json.loads(inkomstenstructuur.content)
    self.inkomsten = iscontent
    inkomstentree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Inkomsten"])

    for groep in iscontent:
        child = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([groep['groep']])
        inkomstentree.addChild(child)
        for categorie in groep['categorien']:
            child2 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([categorie])
            child2.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            child.addChild(child2)

    uitgavenstructuur = requests.get(url="http://localhost:32769/_db/piekenpijp/incoming/uitgavenstructuur")
    uscontent = json.loads(uitgavenstructuur.content)
    self.uitgaven = uscontent
    uitgaventree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Uitgaven"])

    for groep in uscontent:
        child = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([groep['groep']])
        uitgaventree.addChild(child)
        for categorie in groep['categorien']:
            child2 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([categorie])
            child2.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            child.addChild(child2)

    self.treeWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.vinkje)

    self.treeWidget.resize(500, 200)
    self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)
    self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(["Categorie"])
    self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(inkomstentree)
    self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(uitgaventree)
    self.treeWidget.expandItem(uitgaventree)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 2, 1, 1)
```

Comment: you could replace in your example code uitgavenstructuur by the json you receive, you will understand that testing your code is currently impossible.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I should do that in my future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current method creates a *new* item, sets its check-state, and then throws it away without using it. Instead, you need to [find the items](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#findItems) in the tree that you have already created:

```
def checkActiveTreeItems(self):
    for label in self.transactie['transactie']['labels']:
        for item in self.treeWidget.findItems(label, Qt.MatchExactly):
            item.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

Comment: I never got the findItems to work, I gave up on it and put all the items in a dict over which I loop to turn them on or off.